# Generate checksum in vbscript

Tags: file, vbscript, checksum, fciv

I have a tool "File Checksum Integrity Verifier" to generate checksum.

Can anybody help me how to run this tool from vbscript to get checksum for a file?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a) method, so you could read the output from StdOut:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set checksum = sh.Exec("fciv ...")
Do While checksum.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo checksum.StdOut.ReadAll
```